# How to get FirebaseDataBase Snapshot from current user?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

```
private fun getUserInfo() {


val userkey = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$userkey")
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {

    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
        val adapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>()

        p0.children.forEach {
            Log.d("getUserInfo", it.toString())
            val user = it.getValue(User::class.java)
            if (user != null) {
                adapter.add(UserItem(user))
            }
        }

        UserInfo_RCView.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

    }
})
}
}

class UserItem(val user: User): Item<ViewHolder>() {
override fun bind(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    viewHolder.itemView.UsernameSettings_txt.text = user.username

    Picasso.get().load(user.profileImageUrl).into(viewHolder.itemView.ProfileImage_View)
}

override fun getLayout(): Int {
    return R.layout.userinfo
}
}
```

I wanted to make a snapshot from my current user like this, every time I put the `$userkey` in my ref value the app crashes with this error:

> 2018-11-23 22:04:48.414 3871-3871/my.app E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
>   2018-11-23 22:04:49.797 3871-3871/my.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: nobrand.ljb.musicshare, PID: 3871
>       com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type myapp.User

When I didn't put the `$userkey` in my ref value. The app functions as normal put displays all users as expected, but as I said I don't want that.
I'll be thankful for every answer and suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you directly access the correct child node, the loop in your code is not needed anymore.

This means there are two simple ways to do this:

1. Query by key
2. Remove the loop

I'd recommend removing the loop as there's really no need for it anymore, but wanted to show both options.

## Query by key

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users")
ref.orderByKey().equalTo(userkey).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {

    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
        val adapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>()

        p0.children.forEach {
            Log.d("getUserInfo", it.toString())
            val user = it.getValue(User::class.java)
            if (user != null) {
                adapter.add(UserItem(user))
            }
        }

        UserInfo_RCView.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        throw p0.toException();
    }
})
```

## Remove the loop

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$userkey")
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {

    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
        val adapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>()

        val user = p0.getValue(User::class.java)
        if (user != null) {
            adapter.add(UserItem(user))
        }

        UserInfo_RCView.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        throw p0.toException();
    }
})
```